# Tilde-based Paths in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, tilde, tilde-expansion

In Objective-C, how do I go about converting tilde-based pathnames to full pathnames? That is, I'd like to convert from `~/sandbox` to `/Users/TheBobs/sandbox`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use NSString's [`stringByExpandingTildeInPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407716-stringbyexpandingtildeinpath) method.

There are also several other methods that make it easy to [work with paths](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW38).